# React find is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have loadProducts and showProduct functions. loadProducts displays all products while showProduct only that product that is defined through id.

When I place **showProduct(props.match.params.product)** in useEffect instead of **loadProducts()** I get the **products.find is not a function error**. I know it doesn't throw out this error when I use loadProduct but I'd like to use the showProduct function in getProductById(products, productId). I tried return **showProduct($productId)** but there is no desired result.

Here is my function is:

```
...
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({ ...props.product });
    useEffect(() => {
        if (products.length === 0) {
            loadProducts().catch(error => {
                alert("Loading products details" + error);
            });

        } else {
            setProduct({ ...props.product });
        } 

    }, [loadProducts, products.length, props.product]);
...

export function getProductById(products, productId) {
    return products.find(product => product.id.toString() === productId) || null;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {    
    const productId = ownProps.match.params.product;
    const product = getProductById(state.products, productId) ;
    return {
        product,
        products: state.products
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadProducts, showProduct
};
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState();

const productId = props.match.params.product;

useEffect(() => {
  if (!products.length) {
    loadProducts();
  } else {
    if (productId && product.length) {
      const product = getProductById(products, productId);
      setProduct(product);
    }
  }
}, [loadProducts, products, productId]);

export function getProductById(products, productId) {
  return (
    products.find((product) => product.id.toString() === productId) || null
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    products: state.products
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadProducts,
  showProduct
};
```